# How to put data into nested array?

Tags: android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, nested

I am new to android so I need help.

From card-view I will get (Test-name,Test-date,Test-time). different test-name will have different test-date and test-time(Sample format given below)

I want to save the data and send it in the given sample format when I clicked the button. I am not able to find a way how to write a code to save my data in such format. I have researched a bit, I found that it can be done through nested array(maybe I am wrong) I am not sure. Can anyone provide a sample code how can I save the data in such format?

```
{
"testDetails": [{
        "Testname": "abc",
        "TestDate": "2018 - 02 - 01",
        "TestTime": "18: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "Testname": "def",
        "TestDate": "2018 - 03 - 01",
        "TestTime": "18: 50: 00"
    },
    {
        "Testname": "ghi",
        "TestDate": "2018 - 04 - 11",
        "TestTime": "06: 43: 37"
    }
]}
```

Note: This sample is created by me manually so that you can get an idea of how I want the data to appear after saving.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Please, add some details

Comment: This is a json format .where exactly you stuck ?

Comment: @ADM i am not able to write the code how to save my data in that format

Answer (score 0):

Put this is some for loop:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("TestName", "abc");
item.put("TestDate", "2018 - 02 - 01");
item.put("TestTime", "18: 00: 00");
array.put(item);

json.put("testDetails", array);
```